# C printf not working as expected from terminal

Tags: java, c++, c, command-line, terminal

I've reduced the problem as much as I could to the following minimal code snippets. If more info is needed please ask.

Lets say I have a Java class  called A whose main method is this:

```
public static void main (String args[])throws Exception{
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder(args).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
    System.out.println(in.nextLine());
}
```

Basically, it runs a program from the terminal, reads in a line from that program, and echos it. Very simple.

Now I have a second program written in c++ like this:

```
int main() 
{
    string s;
    cout << "example2 in c++"<<endl;;
    cin >> s;
    return 0;
}
```

When I invoke:

```
java A pathToC++Program
```

the program runs as expected, outputting the string sent from the cpp program and terminating.

I have an equivalent program in c:

```
int main()
{
   char s[10];
   printf("example1 in c\n");
   fgets(s,10,stdin); 
   return 0;
}
```

When I invoke:

```
java A pathToCprogram
```

the program halts, and nothing is printed out.

When I remove the fgets line from the c program so that it looks like this:

```
int main()
{
   printf("example1 in c\n");
   return 0;
}
```

then the Java program is able to recognize the line and print it out. Thus it would seem that fgets is the problematic line, yet when fgets was included, even the line before it didn't work.

What is going on here?

(I have no idea if this is a peculiarity of Java or C, so I included both tags.)

Comment: What is your intention with the call to `fgets`? You aren't doing anything with the string you've read in.

Comment: Does gets works instead of fgets. I know we should not use gets but want to ensure the buffer is not playing a role here.

Comment: No gets doesn't work either

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab: **never ever** use `gets`! It is not part of the standard library since 7 years and has been deprecated since more than 20 years even by slow thinkers. It also does no way change the behaviour in regard of input, as it uses the same mechanisms under the hood as `fgets`, just unsafe. Again: It is not "you should not use it", but "you **shall** not use it". Forget it ever existed.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned that in my comment already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing to `stdout` (which is where `printf` will write its output) is by *default* line-buffered, meaning the buffer will be flushed on newline.

***But*** that's the default when running directly from a terminal. If the output is *not* a terminal, then `stdout` will be *fully* buffered, meaning it will only be flushed when you fill the buffer. Or to an explicit `fflush(stdout)` call.

In your C++ program you *do* flush the output explicitly, by using `std::endl` (it writes a newline *and* flushes the buffered output). In your C program there's no such flushing of the output buffer.

This is really very platform specific, but for POSIX platforms (like Linux or macOS) it's like described above. I think it's quite similar for Windows.

As for why it works when you remove the `fgets` statement, it's probably because `fgets` will *block* execution until end-of-file or some (newline-terminated) input have been read. Without the `fgets` the program will exit immediately after `printf` and that will lead to the `stdout` buffer being flushed.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had I feeling the buffer wasn't being flushed, but I couldn't understand why newline wasn't doing it. And yes, I am using windows and you were correct

Comment: Also, even if you don't use `std::endl` (or `std::flush`, or `std::cout.flush()`), `std::cin` and `std:::cout` are tied together by default, so calling `std::cin >> ...` will automatically flush `std::cout` if it hasn't been flushed yet

Answer (score 5):

Passing `std::endl` to `std::cout` in C++ will flush the output buffer.

To flush the output buffer in C, you should add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` line.

Comment: If a newline (`\n`) is present in the format string, the output will be flushed.

Comment: What does output buffering have to do with `fgets`?

Comment: @user1810087 The offending code is written in C, and there a numerous questions around the site that mention issues related to flushing on newlines.